# How to handle reversal which generated 3 IPNs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Recently a customer filed a bank-reversal to a purchase. The purchase was 100 dollars. However the reversal triggered three IPN requests:

Day 1:

```
IPN 1:
  mc_gross=-96.80
  mc_fee=-3.20
  payment_status=Reversed
  reason_code=buyer_complaint
```

Day 2:

```
IPN 2:
  reason_code=unauthorized_spoof
  payment_status=Reversed
  mc_fee=-3.20
  mc_gross=-100.00

IPN 3:
  reason_code=buyer_complaint
  payment_status=Canceled_Reversal
  mc_fee=3.20
  mc_gross=96.80
```

For all three IPNs, the txn_type is nil.

Why would one reversal generate thee IPNs? Which one should be used to do clean up on my end? Would there always be three of them?

I think using `mc_gross` to find the IPN which matches with original amount is not a good idea, because sometimes there are currency conversion losses.

Comment: It looks like in this case you got a buyer complaint, so PayPal put the funds in a temporary holding status, but then the reversal was canceled, so the funds were released back to your account again.  Is that accurate?

Comment: @AndrewAngell I think the fund was put into a temporary status. However at the very end the reversal is completed and all the money went back to the buyer.